# Why can't I authenticate a curl request when piping to less or more?

Tags: curl, pipe

(CentOS 7)

When I try a curl command like `curl -u elastic -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/*' | more`, I find that after typing only a single letter, the command executes as if I have pressed enter, and fails to authenticate.

Is this normal?

I can redirect to a file, or just scroll up, maybe even use wget (haven't tried), or even put my password in the command, but I would like to know what's going on here.

Comment: Have you tried it without `|more` ?

Comment: yes, it works fine without piping, and both with `head` or `tail`. It does not work with `more` or `less`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `curl` and `more` are both reading from the same TTY at the same time. Moreover they are probably both changing the TTY settings; `curl` because the password you type shouldn't be shown on the screen. And `more` because it needs character based input rather than the default line based input.

To prevent that from happening I think you just need to delay starting the `more` command until the `curl` command has started producing output. I don't know of a standard command to do that, but it can be done with two lines of Python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import select
select.select([0], [], [])
```

With the above Python script you can then try this variation of the original command:

```
curl -u elastic -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/*' | ( ./wait.py ; more )
```

Comment: curl -u .... | { sleep 20 ; less ; }    would give you 20 seconds to type the password before less started to read the terminal.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! This makes sense. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

per

```
# curl --help | grep -- ' -u'
 -u, --user USER[:PASSWORD]  Server user and password
#
```

try:

```
curl --silent --user elastic:changeme --request GET localhost:9200/*?pretty | more
```

yet another solution:

```
# pass=changeme
# curl -I -u alexus:$pass https://X.X.X
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.13.5
Date: Wed, 27 Sep 2017 17:27:19 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2350
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Last-Modified: Sun, 13 Aug 2017 18:21:51 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000

#
```

one can also store *pass* variable inside of a file (don't forget to `chmod 700` that file) and use `source` to read variable before running `curl`.

voila!

Comment: "or even put my password in the command, but I would like to know what's going on here" -- I think OP knows that's an option, but would prefer not to do this.

Comment: Indeed. I don't want to see my password saved into my history (especially when I jump into root). I saw a gpgkey technique that could avoid this, but I still want to know why this happens out of curiosity.

Comment: @spanishgum take a look at my updated answer for alternative ways to not to save password in a history.